# Larave - how get in array values from pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot

I have a table pivot from users and courses.

[image]

I need get only the course_id when the column end_at is > today.

So, I created a method in User model for get only this conditional.

```
public function getPurchasedCoursesId()
{
    return $this->courses()->wherePivot('end_at','>=', Carbon::now())->get();

}
```

This return the results correctly but, how make to the result only return the specific column (course_id)
Example result:

```
$course_ids = $user->getPurchasedCoursesId()
dd($coursesids)
Result:
[1, 4, 6, 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#retrieving-results):

```
$this->courses()->wherePivot('end_at','>=', Carbon::now())->pluck('id');
```

The  above is actually pulling the information from the `courses` table rather than the `pivot` table since the data for both will be retrieved in the same query.

Comment: @Alexd2 Glad I could help!